# Python Unicode filename \x01 on Windows

Tags: python, windows, unicode

I have a Python script which generates a bunch of files with various Unicode filenames for testing purposes. It works fine on OS X and Linux environments. On Windows (and more importantly AppVeyor) it fails to create some files, complaining about an invalid filename. Here is a very minimal version:

```py
with open("\x01", "w") as f:
  f.write("foo")
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "genTestRes.py", line 51, in <module>
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(TESTDIR, data))
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'test-res\\\x01'
```

I can reproduce the CI failure locally on a Windows machine with the minimal script above, on an NTFS disk, with Python 2.7. None of these helped:

- adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the beginning
- running `chcp 65001` before the command
- using the Unicode prefix (`u"\x01"`)

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits), NTFS should support at least

> In Win32 namespace: any UTF-16 code unit (case-insensitive) except /:*"?<>| as well as NUL

What could be causing this? `U+0001` should be a perfectly fine, if unprintable, codepoint. Is Wikipedia simply wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows, NTFS filenames cannot contain the ASCII control characters 0x01 - 0x1F. See [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file). This rule applies to all of Microsoft's filesystems, though not necessarily to third-party filesystems. For example, the VirtualBox shared-folder filesystem allows control characters, colon, and pipe in filenames.